# character encoding jruby and normal ruby

Tags: character-encoding, jruby, flash-message

I use The Bootstrap Flash Message Gem and jruby 1.7.0 and have a problem with foreign characters and umlaut in the Flash Message.

Everything works fine when I use a 'normal' ruby like ruby-1.9.3. flash_messages.inspect outputs:
" Felix Meier a été inscrit au sous-groupe 'Administrators'."

but with jruby-1.7.0 the exacltly same Code produces:
" Felix Meier a \xC3\xA9t\xC3\xA9 enlev\xC3\xA9 du sous-groupe 'Administrators'." and I get an Error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):
```

So the question is: Am I doing something wrong, is jruby doing something wrong or the Bootstrap Flash Message Gem the problem?

I tried some stuff on the console but could't reproduce the problem (indication that Flash Message ist the problem?):

```
jruby-1.7.0 :005 >   q="Felix Meier a été inscrit au sous-groupe &#x27;Administrators&#x27;"
 => "Felix Meier a été inscrit au sous-groupe &#x27;Administrators&#x27;" 
jruby-1.7.0 :006 > CGI.unescape(q)
 => "Felix Meier a été inscrit au sous-groupe &#x27;Administrators&#x27;" 
jruby-1.7.0 :007 > CGI.unescape(q).encoding.name
 => "UTF-8" 
jruby-1.7.0 :008 > CGI.unescape(q).valid_encoding?
 => true 
jruby-1.7.0 :009 > r="Felix Meier a \xC3\xA9t\xC3\xA9 enlev\xC3\xA9 du sous-groupe &#x27;Administrators&#x27;"
 => "Felix Meier a été enlevé du sous-groupe &#x27;Administrators&#x27;" 
jruby-1.7.0 :010 > CGI.unescape(r)
 => "Felix Meier a été enlevé du sous-groupe &#x27;Administrators&#x27;" 
jruby-1.7.0 :011 > CGI.unescape(r).encoding.name
 => "UTF-8"
```

Comment: http://www.rorra.com.ar/2010/07/30/rails-3-mysql-and-utf-8/